# Access {__ob__: Observer} in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a project that uses vue 2.x, how do I access {**ob**: Observer} in a different file/function?

I have a function that converts {**ob**: Observer} in a normal object via `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

If I console.log it, I get a normal object but when I store it in data or pass it as a prop, it shows {**ob**: Observer} again and when i try to convert it as a normal object, it shows an empty object {}